# Add the phpmyadmin config to the file?

Tags: linux, apache, phpmyadmin, web-hosting

I try to install phpmyadmin to my VPS and I stuck at somewhere.

The instruction says :

After the installation has completed, add phpmyadmin to the apache configuration.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Add the phpmyadmin config to the file.

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

After I pasted in `sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf` into the CI what should I do?

Comment: `nano` is an editor. you are meant to use it to add the line below to the file. `sudo` is a command that allows you to use the editor with administrative rights. A general remark: you should understand things you do. you should not blindly copy and modify things without having a clue why and what.

Comment: @arkascha ok I saw bunch of text after I opened the file, what's next?

Comment: As said: you should be able to or try to understand that. That is no rocket science. Give it a try.